# Subquery in Substr function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to put subquery in substr function. This is the way I am adding the select statement. But I am getting error.

```
select substr('ABCDEF',2,5) from dual;


select substr('select 'ABCDEF' as val from dual',2,5) from dual;
```

Above mentioned query is just and example i have live query with a table such as

select ',',s.name,'-' from schema.table;

Error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: To the substr function you pass the string literal `'select '`, directly followed by the identifer `ABCDEF` etc. Syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

You would normally do the function call *in* the subquery:

```
select (select substr('ABCDEF', 2, 5) as val from dual)
from dual;
```

However, if you want to treat the subquery as a *scalar* subquery and call it, then the subquery needs its own set of parentheses:

```
select substr( (select 'ABCDEF' as val from dual
               ), 2, 5
             )
from dual;
```

Naming an expression in a subquery has no purpose.  If you want the value to have a name, then name it in the *outer* query:

```
select (select substr('ABCDEF', 2, 5) from dual) as val
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

```
select * from (select substr('ABCDEF', 2, 5) as val from dual)
from dual;
```